# What we call the next consecutive question in series of problem

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, questions, syntactic-analysis

on stack overflow we can edit the questions and this problem is based on that.

*Scenario*

I was asking problem *A* and got the solution of A but face a new problem *B*.

- How do I  mention (reference  back) the problem *A* while telling problem *B*?

  also
- How do I mention  (reference forth) the problem *B* when updating the question  of problem *A* ?

Which one is the correct sentence while writing problem *B* ?

> 1. prior to this question [ link of problem *A* ]
> 2. along with this question [ link of problem *A* ]

it's seems like consecutive question, child question would be asked based on parent question.What we call these kind of questions?

Comment: A "preceding problem", probably.

Comment: How do I mention ? `moving with preceding problem`..is it?

Comment: "Moving with preceding problem" makes no sense to me out of context. You probably should compose several full sample sentences and put them into your question to allow others to better understand in which way do you intend to use the term.

Comment: @CopperKettle . I am looking for the sentence structure. would you please help me

Comment: WRT (with reference to) the previous question [link to previous question], also find the distance of traversal.

Answer (score 3):

Question B is a *follow-up* question to A.

Example usage:

> Having solved my [previous problem with SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26969389), I now have a follow-up question.  When I try using this [WSDL service link](https://www.wirelineonboarding.co.nz/WebServices/OOTInternal/InformationService.asmx?op=AddressVerification), I get an error:
>
> > …

Another example usage:

> Please help me with a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27147950) regarding authentication.

Comment: Yes `follow-up` is right word to tell third person altogether. What I am looking is the sentence structure to mention problem A while describing problem B.Hope you understand my need.

Comment: Do you have a specific example of two related questions?

Comment: Yes. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147950/php-wsdl-soap-issue-server-was-unable-to-process-request-authentication-fail) . I mentioned but feel the lacking the word or sentence structure.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please see my updated question.I also want to mention next problem in previous problem.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, I think:

> As explained in the previous question....
>
> As described in the previous question....